# Equal Chance Probability, Different Numerical Values -- Average is the probability? How to beat the odds?

Tags: probability

- A person is gambling.
- Person has an equal chance to roll on 1 through 50.
- Each roll equals the amount they get (rolling a 45 will get you 45 dollars).

I have no trouble figuring out the average. But I'm having difficulty finding out how many times the person needs to roll in order to "reach" this average or higher.

The actual question is: What are the number of times they must roll to reach a 70%, 80%, and 90% confidence level average?

The average is (1+2+...+49+50)/50 = (n+1)/2 = 25.5 -- I figured, if they roll once they have a 1 in 50 chance of hitting the average. And if they roll twice they have a 1 in 50 chance of hitting average twice?? So 2 in 50? But doing this 50 times does not "guarantee" getting the average. So I'm obviously missing some serious error here.

It's about figuring out how much money is required to hit the "average" amount.

Comment: "To reach" means in sum? I.e. if you roll many times, do you get to keep all previous intake or get whatever the last throw was?

Comment: I hope you mean "get atleast" when you say "reach", because it's pretty darn difficult to get exactly $25.5$ in one throw.

Comment: You have unlimited money and keep rolling until you are 70% certain, 80% certain, 90% certain of getting about 25-26 dollars.

Comment: @Arthur I meant average lol

Comment: The question is more about figuring out how much capital you need to start out with to be sure about getting the average :/

Comment: I spin the wheel.  If 1 comes up, I get 1 dollar.  If 50 comes up, I get 50 dollars. I get to keep any money I win, no matter how much I spin the wheel. How many times must I spin the wheel to make at least 26 dollars? Is that your question?

Comment: @JimGreen That is similar enough I think. My problem keeps coming up in that I don't want the answer to be like: 1 turn if you're this percent lucky, or n-turns if you're this percent unlucky. If that makes sense

Comment: I'm also a total newbie at probability -- This is more an amateur question for myself that I'm trying to figure out

Comment: The rules of the game are clear, but the "chance of getting the average" is not.  As you say, the average is $25.5$. The chance of getting that on one or several rolls is zero, as each roll gets you a whole number. Do you mean the chance of getting at least that much?  That is clearly not 1 in 50, it is $1/2$.  You need to think clearly about your question.  Until you know what it is and explain it clearly, there is no answer.

Comment: As arther has said above it's not about getting 25.5 (which can't be rolled), it's about how many rolls it takes to reach the average for that many rolls with a confidence of 70, 80, and 90%.

Comment: Hit enter by accident: Meaning if you roll twice, average is 51; for three rolls the average is 21.5*3; ad infinitum. However what you actually roll could be 21 or less two times in a row (less than 50% chance). So I have difficulty figuring out after how many rolls it becomes less than 10% likely to be under average

Comment: According to jim green below after two rolls it's 88% likely to be on par with the "average", and 98% likely on three rolls to be around 21.5*3. However, I really would like to know how to calculate this and the concept behind it which is why I haven't scored it yet as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote a little program to spin that wheel 10,000,000 times. And then I ran it multiple times.

Hitting/beating the average (26) on a 1-50 wheel:

1 spin : 50%

2 spins: 38%

3 spins: 10%

4 spins:  2%

5-8 spins: less than 0.2% (that's total, not each)

Since I don't know the cost of a spin, I can't finish your calculations, but I hope this is close to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a sampling distribution. A sampling distribution is a distribution of the averages of doing something N times. So, all your sampling distributions are centered at 25.5, you're correct there. What I gather you're asking is what the relationship between N and the chance of you getting at least average. This probability remains fixed. You will always have a 50% chance of getting average or higher, as all sampling distributions are normal, symmetric distributions. However, as N increases, variability decreases. So you become less likely to be very far off the mean.

Comment: Yes! So how can I calculate "How likely" I am from the mean based on N?

Comment: Also how would an exponential sampling distribution affect N?

Comment: Sampling distributions are only normal if the population has a finite variance (as is the case here). Some distributions have infinite variance.

Comment: I calculated your STDEV to be 14.577. Standard deviation of a sampling distribution is STDEV/SQRT(N) so plug in that equation and then just use your continues normal probability functions.